# program works but doesn't catch an exception like i need

Tags: java, try-catch

I need a try-catch that actually works, rather than just if length > 0 && width > 0.  It works but if you put any letters in it just shuts down the program with a generic message.  I have tried to do it in a do loop and couldn't figure it out.  Any help would be awesome.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rectangle {

    public static int rectangleArea(int length, int width) {

        int area;

        area = length * width;
        return area;
    }

    public static double rectangleRatio(int length, int width) {

        double ratio;

        ratio = (double) width / length;
        return 2 * ratio;
    }

    public static void main(String[] str) {
        int width;
        int length;

        while (true) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Welcome to the Rectangle Calculator!\n");

            System.out.println("Enter a valid Length of the Rectangle :");
            length = scan.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter a valid Width of the Rectangle :");
            width = scan.nextInt();

            if (width > 0 && length > 0) {
                break;
            } else {
                continue;
            }

        }

        int area = rectangleArea(length, width);
        double ratio = rectangleRatio(length, width);

        System.out.printf("%s%d%s%d%s%d%s%.3f", "\nLength of the Rectangle:  ", length, "\nWidth of the Rectangle:  ",
                width, "\nArea of the Rectangle:  ", area, "\nRatio of the Rectangle:  ", ratio);

        System.out.println("\n\nThank you for using the Rectangle Calculator. ");

    }

}
```

Comment: Please see the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page. "You put any letters in..." what? You're asking how to validate the input? It won't catch an exception if there's no exception handling in place. Can you be more specific?

Comment: The message may appear generic to you, but to someone with more experience, it may have meaning. Whenever you post about a problem, you need to include the full text of any error messages you encounter. By the way: InputMismatchException is not "generic" in any way.

Comment: Sorry, I was not very clear. What I have learned so far in class about try-catch exceptions looks like   try { Sysytem.out.println("Please enter length");  scan.nextInt();  break;  } catch (Exception ex) {  System.println("Please enter whole numbers only " + ex);  scan.nextLine(); } while (true);

Comment: Yes. If you put this try/catch and your input statements into a loop, it will repeat every time there is an error in the input. Generally you want a generic statement there. It's best to only catch the type of statement you want to deal with, in this case an InputMismatchException.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Rectangle {

    public static int rectangleArea(int length, int width) {

        int area;

        area = length * width;
        return area;
    }

    public static double rectangleRatio(int length, int width) {

        double ratio;

        ratio = (double) width / length;
        return 2 * ratio;
    }

    public static void main(String[] str) {
        int width = 0;
        int length = 0;
        boolean valid;

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Rectangle Calculator!\n");

        do {
            valid = true;
            System.out.print("Enter a valid Length of the Rectangle :");
            try {
                length = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
                if (length <= 0) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again");
                valid = false;
            }
        } while (!valid);

        do {
            valid = true;
            System.out.print("Enter a valid Width of the Rectangle :");
            try {
                width = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
                if (width <= 0) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again");
                valid = false;
            }
        } while (!valid);

        int area = rectangleArea(length, width);
        double ratio = rectangleRatio(length, width);

        System.out.printf("%s%d%s%d%s%d%s%.3f", "\nLength of the Rectangle:  ", length, "\nWidth of the Rectangle:  ",
                width, "\nArea of the Rectangle:  ", area, "\nRatio of the Rectangle:  ", ratio);

        System.out.println("\n\nThank you for using the Rectangle Calculator. ");
    }
}
```

**A sample run:**

```
Welcome to the Rectangle Calculator!

Enter a valid Length of the Rectangle :a
Invalid input. Try again
Enter a valid Length of the Rectangle :-5
Invalid input. Try again
Enter a valid Length of the Rectangle :5
Enter a valid Width of the Rectangle :b
Invalid input. Try again
Enter a valid Width of the Rectangle :-6
Invalid input. Try again
Enter a valid Width of the Rectangle :6

Length of the Rectangle:  5
Width of the Rectangle:  6
Area of the Rectangle:  30
Ratio of the Rectangle:  2.400

Thank you for using the Rectangle Calculator.
```

Comment: It might be better to change those tests to `<= 0`.

Comment: Thanks, @DavidConrad for the valuable feedback. I've updated the answer to incorporate your suggestion.

Comment: per my assignment "widths and lengths cannot be less than or equal to 0."

Comment: @JeremyCunion - In that case, just replace `<=` with `<`. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt/issue.

Comment: also as this is a beginner java class instead of IllegalArguementException is it easy to change to be as simple as an (Exception as ex)?

Comment: Yes, of course, you can replace `IllegalArgumentException` with `Exception`. However, I recommend you use `IllegalArgumentException` because it specifies the problem categorically while `Exception` is generic.

Comment: @JeremyCunion they cannot be less than or equal to 0, which is why you want to throw an exception and give an error message if they are `<= 0`.

Answer (score 0):

You are expecting only int value using `scan.nextInt()` but you are testing with any random character. Because of this, it is throwing an exception.
So, first you need to check if it is an int or not. If input value is not an int then continue.

```
while (true) {
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Welcome to the Rectangle Calculator!\n");

            System.out.println("Enter a valid Length of the Rectangle :");
            if(!scan.hasNextInt()){
                System.out.println("Please enter only  integer for length");
                continue;
            }
            length = scan.nextInt();

            System.out.println("Enter a valid Width of the Rectangle :");
            if(!scan.hasNextInt()){
                System.out.println("Please enter only  integer for Width");
                continue;
            }
            width = scan.nextInt();

            if (width > 0 && length > 0) {
                break;
            } else {
                continue;
            }

        }
```

Comment: This won't work because once you've entered something that isn't an int, it will continue the loop forever. Also, it shouldn't create a Scanner every time around the loop, but you picked that up from the OP.